# How to get all hockey matches links?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i create simple script but i dont know how can I continue to solve problem.

There is website: https://www.ice.hockey/en/schedule/schedule

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.ice.hockey/en/schedule/schedule")

driver.implicitly_wait(10) # Wait up to 10 seconds

links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
all_links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links if link.get_attribute('href')]

for url in all_links:
    print(url)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Are you getting any errors/exceptions? Sharing it in your question will help.